# Chrome/FF API for operating with tab's Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, google-chrome, tabs

I need to control site's javascript via global hotkeys.
I'm trying to control javascript's audio player via Windows Global hotkeys.

But can't understand how to do it.

Language: C#/C++ (Qt). No matter.
Browser: Chrome (maybe other, no matter)

Comment: I think you might want to re-tag you question a bit better.

Comment: I might be jumping the gun here, but I'm pretty sure you can't send keystrokes to a web-page unless it is in focus and receiving keystrokes directly. Flash/Silverlight/Java-Applets might have a much better API/Hooks to achieve this, but with Security and Sandboxing in place for JS, I don't think you can.

Comment: I agree with bPratik. Unless you find a way to write a browser extension or plugin of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery keypress http://api.jquery.com/keypress/
According to the documentation this event will only fire when the element it set upon is focussed.

```
$(someElement).keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which, e.keyCode); 
    // according to one of the comments e.which should be used in every browser other than IE.


})
```

Comment: I don't believe OP is looking to capture keystrokes on the page as you suggest. More like wanting to capture Play/Pause events fired at OS level. I think what OP means by "Global Hotkeys" is the likes of "Dedicated Media Keys" like the ones you find on fancy keyboards, for instance.

Comment: @bPratik I mean Winkey+LEFTARROW (prev track), Winkey+RIGHTARROW (next track..). Yeah, I need to catch at OS level and send to browser some javascript.

Comment: I dont think this will happen.